# Is it possible to use StanfordCoreNLP to get constituency parsing while using a preexisting tokenization?

Tags: stanford-nlp

As per the title of this post, I would like to know if it is possible to use StanfordCoreNLP to get a constituency parsing of a text while using a pre-existing, potentially externaly provided tokenization of the text. I am looking to do this on texts written in French. I guess that if it were possible, only the file containing the description the tokens would be necessary, since a version of the text could be reconstructed from this file.
I suppose it might be possible if one were to program in java, and directly use the java classes, but since I do not know much java, I wanted to know if such a thing was possible using command-line instruction.
Has anyone knowledge about such a thing?

I searched for an answer to this question by googling, and browsing the StanfordCoreNLP site (https://nlp.stanford.edu/), especially this page https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/, but did not find what I was looking for. When looking for a way to get info about the software, I found that we are told to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Now for a precise formulation of my question: is there a way to use the StanfordCoreNLP with the command-line interface so as to get constituency parsing info on a text written in French while forcing StanfordCoreNLP to respect a pre-existing, input tokenization of that text? If the answer is yes, where can I document myself about such a way?

**Edit:**
*Example :*
I will provide an example of such a thing being done on a text written in English :

Raw text :
« John went on a trip; which was quite nice. »

Tokenized text :
«  John went on a trip ; which was quite nice . »
(Here, the difference from the raw text is that the punctuation marks were separated from their respective preceding word)

Constituency parsing of the text :
«  (ROOT (S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (VBD went) (PP (IN on) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN trip)) (: ;) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT which)) (S (VP (VBD was) (ADJP (RB quite) (JJ nice)))))))) (. .))) »

As you can see, the constituency parsing can be seen as an annotation of the result of the tokenization step. I currently know how to use the StanfordCoreNLP suite to compute constituency parsing information, among other type of information, by providing the raw text, but I guess that, in order to achieve that, the StanfordCoreNLP suite carries out its own tokenization step.

I would like to know if there is a way to force the StanfordCoreNLP suite to use / respect a pre-defined tokenization of a text in French.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for the answer. Incidentally, that made me learn how one can parametrize the different annotators used during a StanfordCoreNLP's pipeline process, using the "{annotator_name}.{option_name}" format on the command line; so next time I will be able to better understand the StanfordCoreNLP's documentation when browsing it.

Comment: A few comments to improve your question thereby helping others answer it : 
1. Give examples to illustrate what you want to achieve.
2. Write down the approaches you have already tried.
3. Summarize the question you want to ask and put it at the end. Be very specific with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tokenize.whitespace` option, and provide your text tokenized by whitespace.  That option will only create words separated by whitespace.